# Random variable X draw from Gassuain distritbuion

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, normal-distribution

I'm thinking about the following question:
image X is a random variable drawn from a Gaussian distribution with a mean of μ and σ. If (μ,log(σ)) is drawn from a two-dimensional Gaussian distribution with known **μ** (2-dimensional) and covariance matrix **Σ** (2 by 2 matrix), what the distribution of X would be like?

To make the question more general, imagine a random vector **X** (D dimensions) drawn from a D-dimensional Gaussian distribution. The covariance matrix's off-diagonal element of this D-dimensional Gaussian distribution is 0. The log of the diagonal elements of the covariance matrix, and the corresponding mean values are drawn from another 2D-dimensional Gaussian distribution, which we know its covariance matrix (2D by 2D matrix) and the corresponding means (2D vector). Can we calculate **X**'s distribution?

I'm not from math background and could not figure it out. Any information would be highly appreciated!

Comment: One technical issue: if the pair $(\mu, \sigma)$ is itself drawn from a 2-dimensional Gaussian distribution, then it is possible for $\sigma$ to be negative, which does not make sense.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I should have said log(σ) is drawn from the Gaussian distribution. It is corrected now.